# How to keep DIV from overlapping?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am making a CSS design for a SIM game I play, and a customer asked for 4 boxes, two large and in between them, two horizontally aligned boxes. They work fine, unless I try and add headers. The entire website is set up in a ridiculous amount of tables, basically coding from the 90s. All boxes I have made are div and aligned to meet up with the existing boxes on the page.

The main boxes are how I want the headers on all four boxes, separate and do not scroll. However, as you can see from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bEsE/1/), nothing is aligning. When I try to put headers on the horizontal boxes, it really messes up the align.  I am a fairly new coder, and would greatly appreciate some help.

```
div {
display: block;
color: #fff;
}
.topcontain{
width:500px;
height:300px;
}
.topleftbox {
width:240px;
height:300px;
overflow:auto;
float:left;
background:#505665;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
font-family: 'Snippet', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px!important;
margin: 5px;
opacity: .75;
}

.toprightbox {
width:240px;
height:300px;
overflow:auto;
float:right;
background:#505665;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
font-family: 'Snippet', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px!important;
margin: 5px;
opacity: .75;
}
.bottomcontain {
width:500px;
height:300px;
}
.header {
width:500px;
float:center;
background:#060e23;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
font-size: 14px;
border: 1px solid #030711;
opacity: 1.0;
}
.bottombox {
width:500px;
height:300px;
overflow:auto;
float:center;
background:#505665;
font-size: 12px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
font-family: 'Snippet', sans-serif;
opacity: .75;
}
.credit {
width:500px;
float:center;
background:#060e23;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
font-size: 12px;
border: 1px solid #030711;
opacity: .85;
}
.top {
font-family: 'Snippet', sans-serif;
background : #060e23;
color : #fff;
font-size : 15px;
padding : 5px 15px;
font-weight : normal;
text-align : center;
border: 1px solid #030711;
opacity: .90;
}
```

Here is how it looks on the page I am coding:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s6ka.png)

Thank you again!

Comment: Your CSS repeats itself way too much. Its quite confusing. You should try some consolidation. `toprightbox` and `topleftbox` are the same except for the float. So if you just add another class you can say `.box { //all that code}` `.topleftbox { float: left}` `.toprightbox { float: right)` it's much neater

Comment: @GEspinha it kind of is if it effects the ability to answer the question

Comment: @Adjit Oh, wait, I guess you are right, im sorry ;)

Comment: @GEspinha no worries, but when the CSS is super redundant it makes it hard to single out an issue, especially when there are multiple issues. The OP needs to try and replicate the problem in a brief example replicating the issue. Not just throwing us their wall of CSS. 90% of the time, when I go to put a question up on SO while trying to replicate the issue in jsFiddle, I answer my own question because I single out the issue and makes it easier to see whats going on.

Comment: @Adjit I did originally put everything in a much simpler form, however with my case nothing would work unless paired with the code for the entire website. Anyway, the issue is solved, thank you.

Comment: @Echo I would strongly suggest getting a book on HTML and CSS

Comment: @Adjit I already have multiple books, excuse me for having a hiccup in my knowledge. I would appreciate if no other posts on this question were made.

Comment: @Echo understandable. Sorry if I came off harsh. The console (f12) in Chrome is very useful. It can also help you single out un-needed CSS properties because it can allow you to turn properties on and off. Makes it easy to see what is really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6bEsE/6/

```
   <div class="bottomcontain">
      <div class="header">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="bottombox">
         [TOP]
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="topcontain">
        <div class="topleftbox">
            <div class="top">Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>
                [MIDDLE LEFT]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toprightbox">
            <div class="top">Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>
                [MIDDLE RIGHT]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="bottomcontain">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="bottombox">
            [BOTTOM]
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="credit">Layout and CSS by Echo [#15480]</div>
```

I did a fast clean of your code (5 minutes)
But it is far from finishing it

First of all, you have bad closing of divs.
Second, you have fixed height for divs. A div with fixed width and height and more text than can fit in it will create scrolls.

before inserting all that text, try to fix the containers starting from the simple example i provided above. Also you may need to change a bit the html structure, to group those floating middle divs.

Answer (score 0):

### [*Demo Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/6bEsE/4/)

In CSS

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: It worked great in the Fiddle, but on [the site](http://i.imgur.com/kvcBPti.png) it is still jumbled. But thank you.

Comment: @Echo What exactly should it look like..?

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57m33/1/) with all of the sites code, to show you what is happening.

The headers are separated from the main box.